# Как можно поменять стили внутри iFrame?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

Есть сайт http://leiberlsh.v55372.goserver.host/woid4tla/ где товары загружаются через iFrame. Как можно поменять стили внутри самого iFrame?

Comment: Никак практически, используйте ajax и php

Comment: Поскольку вы грузите iframe с другого домена, то не практически, а совершенно и определенно - никак. Это политика безопасности.